# i think i got infinite loop for this BST

Tags: f#, tree

this code i got is from Alexander Battisti about how to make a tree from a list of data:

```
let data = [4;3;8;7;10;1;9;6;5;0;2]

type Tree<'a> = 
    | Node of Tree<'a> * 'a * Tree<'a>
    | Leaf

let rec insert tree element = 
    match element,tree with
    | x,Leaf        -> Node(Leaf,x,Leaf)
    | x,Node(l,y,r) when x <= y -> Node((insert l x),y,r)
    | x,Node(l,y,r) when x > y -> Node(l,y,(insert r x))
    | _ -> Leaf


let makeTree = List.fold insert Leaf data
```

then i want to implement this code to my binary search tree code

```
let rec BinarySearch tree element = 
    match element,tree with
    | x,Leaf   -> BinarySearch (Node(Leaf,x,Leaf)) x
    | x,Node(l,y,r) when x<=y ->
        BinarySearch l y
    | x,Node(l,y,r) when x>y ->
        BinarySearch r y
    | x,Node(l,y,r) when x=y ->
        true
    | _ -> false
```

then i use my search code like this:

```
> BinarySearch makeTree 5;;
```

and the result is none because it's like i got an infinite looping
can someone help me? if my code is wrong, please help me to correct it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution by Yin is how I would write it too.

Anyway, here is a solution that is closer to your version and (hopefully) explains what went wrong:

```
let rec BinarySearch tree element = 
  match element,tree with
  | x, Leaf   -> 
     // You originally called 'BinarySearch' here, but that's wrong - if we reach
     // the leaf of the tree (on the path from root to leaf) then we know that the
     // element is not in the tree so we return false
     false
  | x, Node(l,y,r) when x<y ->// This needs to be 'x<y', otherwise the clause would be
                              // matched when 'x=y' and we wouldn't find the element!
     BinarySearch l element   // Your recursive call was 'BinarySearch l y' but
                              // that's wrong - you want to search for 'element'
  | x, Node(l,y,r) when x>y ->
      BinarySearch r element
  | x,Node(l,y,r) ->          // You can simplify the code by omitting the 'when' 
      true                    // clause (because this will only be reached when
                              // x=y. Then you can omit the last (unreachable) case
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let rec BinarySearch tree element = 
    match tree with
    | Leaf -> false
    | Node(l, v, r) ->
        if v = element then 
            true
        elif v < element then
            BinarySearch r element
        else
            BinarySearch l element


BinarySearch makeTree 5
```